# How do I show only 2 columns but specific row data entries?

Tags: r

[image]

I only need the area.name column and the daily.lab.confirmed.cases column. How do I get it to show me just the London data under area.name because at the moment it's showing me all of the data entries

Comment: This is a basic subsetting/indexing question. You can use the `subset()` function or square brackets for indexing, e.g., `dat[dat$area.name == 'London', c('area.name', 'daily.cases')]`. Both of these are available in base R. You can find more info in this excellent introduction: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf in section 2. There are also newer (perhaps more complicated, depending on your perspective) approaches available through the tidyverse packages. There is a lot of information on these options available online as well.

Answer (score 0):

I created a reproducible data sample:

```
df <- data.frame(Area.name = c("Birmingham", "London", "Newcastle"),
                 Area.code = c("EO8000025", "EO8000026", "EO8000027"),
                 Area.type = c("utla", "utla", "utla"),
                 Specimen.date = c("24/04/2020", "24/04/2020", "24/04/2020"),
                 Daily.lab.confirmed.cases = c(72, 91, 107),
                 Cumulative.lab.confirmed.cases = c(2905, 2833, 2742))

   Area.name Area.code Area.type Specimen.date Daily.lab.confirmed.cases Cumulative.lab.confirmed.cases
1 Birmingham EO8000025      utla    24/04/2020                        72                           2905
2     London EO8000026      utla    24/04/2020                        91                           2833
3  Newcastle EO8000027      utla    24/04/2020                       107                           2742
```

You can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  filter(Area.name == "London") %>%
  select(Area.name, Daily.lab.confirmed.cases)
```

Output:

```
  Area.name Daily.lab.confirmed.cases
1    London                        91
```

Comment: @Charlotte, you mean sum all the values Daily.lab.confirmed.cases of London?

Comment: To sum the cases i used this code is this correct: sum(cases %>%
  filter(Area.name == "London") %>%
  select(Daily.lab.confirmed.cases))

Comment: @Charlotte, you should add then the code summarise(sum = sum(Daily.lab.confirmed.cases)) after my code.